# Rotating Line by $\theta$ and Obtaining Parametric Equation

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations

I have two lines $y=5$ and $x=5$. I want to rotate the lines with the center of rotation at origin. How can I obtain the parametric equation for the line as follows $y=mx+c$?

I am solving it as follows:

Use $\tan(\theta)$ for slope, so $y=\tan(\theta)x+c$ How do I get $c$? How do I do same for $y=5$ and $x=5$ lines?

Comment: What is the coordinates of the point on the rotated line closest to the origin? The case is different for $y=5$ and $x=5$.

Comment: Use the fact the perpendicular distance of the line from origin is $5$.

Comment: $c$ will vary depending on $\theta$. As @SarGe said, the line will always be perpendicular to the origin and at a distance of $5$. It is a tangent to a circle of radius $5$ with its center at origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at a line with equation
$$
Ax + By + C = 0
$$
Picking $A = 1, B = 0, C = -5$ gives the line $x = 5$. I'll bet that you can find the $A,B,C$ that work for $y = 5$.

Now you want to rotate this line by $\theta$, which is to say that if
$$
P = (x, y)
$$
is a point on the first line, then you want
$$
P' = (x \cos \theta - y\sin \theta, x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta)
$$
to be a point on the new line, with some new coefficients $A', B', C'$. So
let's write that out. You want to have
$$
A' (x \cos \theta - y\sin \theta) + B'(x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta) + C' = 0.
$$
To save some typing, I'm going to write $s$ for $\sin \theta$ and $c$ for $\cos \theta$, so this becomes
$$
A' (cx - sy) + B'(sx + cy) + C' = 0.
$$
Reversing the two sides and doing a little algebra, we have
\begin{align}
0 
&= A' (cx - sy) + B'(sx + cy) + C' \\
&= cA'x - sA'y + sB'x + cB'y + C' \\
&= (cA' + sB')x +  (-sA' + cB')y + C' \\
\end{align}
Now we know (because $P$ is on the original line) that
$$
Ax + By + C = 0
$$
The thing we *want* to be true would work out if
\begin{align}
A &= cA' + sB'\\
B &= -sA' + cB'\\
C' &= C\\
\end{align}

Can we find the numbers $A'$ and $B'$ from this? It turns out that we can. Multiply the first equations by $c$ and $-s$, respectively, to get

\begin{align}
cA &= c^2A' + scB'\\
-sB &= s^2A' - scB'\\
\end{align}
and then add them together to get
\begin{align}
cA - sB &= (c^2 + s^2)A' + scB' - scB'\\
cA - sB &= A'
\end{align}
where the last simplification comes from cancelling the $scB'$ terms, and converting $c^2 + s^2 = \sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta$ to $1$.

And now we have a formula for $A'$. Similarly, multiplying the first equation by $s$ and the second by $c$, we get
\begin{align}
sA &= scA' + s^2B'\\
cB &= -csA' + c^2B'\\
sA + cB &= scA' + s^2B' - csA' + c^2 B'\\
sA + cB &= s^2B'+ c^2 B'\\
sA + cB &= (s^2+ c^2) B'\\
sA + cB &= B'\\
\end{align}

And there you have it: the "rotated" version of the line
$$
Ax + By + C = 0
$$
is the line
$$
(cA - sB)x + (sA + cB) y + C = 0
$$
As an example, for your first line, defined by $A = 1, B = 0, C -5$,
if $\theta$ is 30 degrees, then
$$
s = \sin \theta = 0.5\\
c = \cos \theta \approx 0.866
$$
Thus the (approximate) new line is
\begin{align}
0 &= A'x + B' y + C'\\ 
0 &= (cA - sB)x + (sA + cB) y + C \\
0 &= (c\cdot1 - s \cdot 0)x + (s \cdot 1 + c\cdot 0) y -5 & \text{substitute in values of $A,B,C$}\\
 0 &= (c)x + (s) y -5 & \text{simplifying} \\
 0 &= 0.866x + \frac{1}{2} y -5 & \text{substituting numbers for $c$ and $s$} \\
 5 &= 0.866x + \frac{1}{2} y & \text{moving constant to the other side} \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Take line $x = 5$. When you rotate it with center as the origin, the line will always be a tangent to the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 5^2 \,$ or $\,x = 5cos\theta, \, y = 5sin \theta$.

$\frac{dy}{dx} = - \cot \theta$

Equation of line at a point on circle $(5 \cos \theta, 5 \sin \theta)$ will be

$(y - 5\sin\theta) = -\cot \theta (x - 5\cos\theta)$ as the point is also on the tangent line.

You can do similarly for line $y = 5$. The equation of the line will be $90^0$ ahead (assuming anti-clockwise rotation) but overall you will get the same set of tangent lines as the circle is the same.